# Why I've error in fetching each object as array?

Tags: php, json, curl, yql

I'm trying to print the result of an API call individually.
I'm making an call to YQL API call.

Here is the PHP script that I m using

```
  <?php
  if (!$_REQUEST["q"]) return;

  $query = $_REQUEST["q"];

  $q = "'http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=$query'";

  $query = "select * from xml where url=$q";
  $url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
  $url .= rawurlencode($query);
  $url .= "&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

  function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
 }

$data = get_data($url);

 // decode the data and get the first result set.
 $info = json_decode($data);

 foreach( $info['suggestion']['data'] as $i ) {
 echo $i;
 }
 ?>
```

And the result I get from the API call is

```
cbfunc({
"query": {
"count": 1,
"created": "2012-04-06T06:13:57Z",
"lang": "en-US",
"diagnostics": {
"publiclyCallable": "true",
"url": {
"execution-start-time": "2",
"execution-stop-time": "59",
"execution-time": "57",
"proxy": "DEFAULT",
"content": "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=fb"
 },
 "user-time": "59",
 "service-time": "57",
 "build-version": "26247"
 },
"results": {
"toplevel": {
"CompleteSuggestion": [
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fb"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "1260000000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbi"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "155000000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbi most wanted"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "54800000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbi jobs"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "119000000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fb covers"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "82100000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fb banners"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "13300000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbook"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "4050000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbisd"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "84300"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbanners"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "789000"
  }
 },
 {
  "suggestion": {
   "data": "fbo"
  },
  "num_queries": {
   "int": "13000000"
   }
  }
 ]
}
}
}
});
```

I'm trying to iterate over the suggestions Object and I'm trying to print the data property of the suggestion object.

And I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solve your problem:

```
foreach( $info['query']['results']['toplevel']['CompleteSuggestion'] as $i ) {
 echo $i['suggestion']['data'];
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is returning your data wrapped by a javascript callback function `cbfunc(JSON_RESPONSE_DATA);`....you can remove the `cbfunc(` from the start and `);` from the end and the do `print_r(json_decode(REST_OF_THE_RESPONSE, true));`...and voila!...you get the array...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To array output you need put `true` parameters as second. Otherwise its returning object. See: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
// decode the data and get the first result set.
$info = json_decode($data, true);
//var_dump($info);

foreach( $info['suggestion']['data'] as $i ) {
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: I m trying to echo the data property of the suggestion object individually. And here's the code that I m using for it.     foreach( $info['CompleteSuggestion']['suggestion'] as $i ) {
echo $i['data'];
}

Comment: But I m still getting undefined index error

Comment: Nope still getting error Undefined index: CompleteSuggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `json_decode($data, true);`. See manual: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

> Second param When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.